# Manually create a multi-sheet file for excel from C

Tags: c, excel, export-to-excel

I am working on a C application. I was planning on using a CSV file to read the values into a spread sheet, but then as the data got more and more complex (around 100 cols), I saw the need to start to do multiple sheets. I am working on a single board computer, and the file is used for storing diagnostic information. I would like to be able to write the file from the SBC in an ASCII format, and then import it to excel (or the open source alternative), and have multiple sheets. Is this even possible, or should I start working on macros to run on the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe consider using XML to write the data, then it can easily be transformed into whatever format you want, and you can have the data be emitted in a way that make semantic sense rather than according to the architecture of a spreadsheet. This might allow more flexibility for different external programs to interact with the data. You can use XSLT to transform it into multiple CSV files if that's desired and there is probably reasonable ways to import it into spreadsheets directly.